# Pattern based data filtering from strings not working PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I have number of strings from which I need to filter out the specific data based on keywords or any special characters we can have.

The examples strings actually looks like these (I am adding more in code comments):

**String Pattern 1:**

```
Expiration Fee: 5 LONG US Tech 100 (Mar) 4190-4390 (4:15PM) @ 4291
```

What I need from this is **only highlighted one by**`|`:

`5 LONG US Tech 100` | `Mar` | `4190-4390` | `4:15PM` | `4291`

**String Pattern 2:**

```
10 US 500 (Mar) >2051.0 (4:15PM) @ 22
```

What I need from this is **only highlighted one by**`|`:

`10 US 500` | `Mar` | `2051.0` | `4:15PM` | `22`

**String Pattern 3:**

```
2 LONG AUD/USD >.8130 (4:20PM) @ 66
```

What I need from this is **only highlighted one by**`|`:

`2 LONG AUD/USD` | `.8130` | `4:20PM` | `66`

I am using very basic level code to get this done but it is also not working as it should work.

So, my problem is to filter the desired data from number of strings upon number of factors I have mentioned.

I would like to go with some `PHP regex` with number of `if/else` as I think that would work best here.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$finaltr_one    = "Expiration Fee: 10 LONG AUD/USD >.8189 (9:50AM) @ 90.5";
// I need: 10 LONG AUD/USD | .8189 | 9:50AM | 90.5 

$finaltr_one    = "10 Wall St 30 (Mar) >17900 (4:15PM) @ 69.5";
// I need: 10 Wall St 30 | 17900 | 4:15PM | 69.5 

$finaltr_one    = "1 GBP/USD >1.5173 (10:05AM) @ 3.5";
// I need: 1 GBP/USD | 1.5173 | 10:05AM | 3.5

$finaltr_one    = "Expiration Fee: 1 SHORT GBP/USD >1.5173 (10:05AM) @ 3.5";
// I need: 1 SHORT GBP/USD | 1.5173 | 10:05AM | 3.5

$finaltr_one    = "Expiration Fee: 7 LONG US 500 (Mar) >2022.0 (4:15PM) @ 95";
// I need: 7 LONG US 500 | Mar | 2022.0 | 4:15PM | 95

$finaltr_one    = "5 LONG US Tech 100 (Mar) 4190-4390 (4:15PM) @ 4291";
// I need: 5 LONG US Tech 100 | Mar | 4190-4390 | 4:15PM | 4291 
// OR
// I need: 5 LONG US Tech 100 | Mar | 4190 | 4:15PM | 4291 

$finaltr_one    = "2 Wall St 30 (Mar) 18000-18100 (12PM) @ 18023";
// I need: 2 Wall St 30 | Mar | 18000-18100 | 12PM | 18023
// OR
// I need: 2 Wall St 30 | Mar | 18000 | 12PM | 18023

if(strpos("Expiration Fee: ", $finaltr_one)!==FALSE)
{

$var_one = explode("Expiration Fee: ", $finaltr_one);

$match = array(' (',') >',' (',') @ ');

$fmatch = str_replace($match, " | ", $var_one[1]);

$final = explode(" | ", $fmatch);

    }else{


$match = array(' (',') >',' (',') @ ');

$fmatch = str_replace($match, " ! ", $finaltr_one);

$final = explode(" ! ", $fmatch);

}
?>
```

Comment: The comments in your code are asking for a different output than you did in your description. Which is desired? Also, presumably you are looking for a regex that will handle more than just these specific examples - can you discuss the format of the input/output more generally?

Comment: Basically, the desired input/output will be the one I have added in comments and code.

Comment: The use of `regex` will be much better as these strings are almost the same and have much in number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test all of your test cases, but the first 3 match nicely with this:

```
/(?:Expiration Fee: )?(\d+\s+(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\/]+\s+)*)(?:\(([a-zA-Z]+)\)\s+)?(?:>([0-9.]+)\s+)?(?:(\d+-\d+)\s+)?(?:\((\d{1,2}(?::\d{2})?[AP]M)\)\s+)?(?:@\s+([\d.]+))/
```

If you hold that string in $re then you could do something like this:

```
$strs = array("Expiration Fee: 10 LONG AUD/USD >.8189 (9:50AM) @ 90.5",
              "10 Wall St 30 (Mar) >17900 (4:15PM) @ 69.5",
               ...);
foreach ($strs as $subject) {
    echo "======<br />\n$subject<br />\n";
    if (preg_match($re, $subject, $m))
        for ($i=1; $i<count($m); $i++)
            if ($m[$i]) echo "$m[$i]<br />\n";
}
```

and you'll see that $m contains all the values you are looking for in elements 1-n.

Comment: Sorry, its not working. If you review this: `Array ( [0] => Expiration Fee: 10 LONG AUD/USD >.8189 (9:50AM) @ 90.5 [1] => 10 [2] => LONG AUD/USD [3] => [4] => .8189 [5] => 9:50AM [6] => 90.5 )` Here I only need `Array ( [0] => 10 LONG AUD/USD [1]  => .8189 [3] => 9:50AM`

Comment: Its not working for: `$subject = "2 Wall St 30 (Mar) 18000-18100 (12PM) @ 18023";` and its output should be: `Array ( [0] => 2 Wall St 30  [1] => Mar  [2] => 18000-18100  [3] => 12PM)`

Comment: It somehow only works with `$subject = "1 AUD/USD >.8114 (11:35AM) @ 87";` but not like this one `Array ( [0] => 1 AUD/USD [1] => .8114 [2] => 11:35AM [3] => 87)`

Comment: There are going to be empty elements in your array. You'll just have to handle them programmatically.  In your first comment above why don't you want the 90.5 at the end?

Comment: I've got it working now for the 18000-18100 example (2nd comment above)

Comment: ok fine. I am sorry for the type. It should look like this: `Array ( [0] => 10 LONG AUD/USD [1] => .8189 [2] => 9:50AM [3] => 90.5 )`

Comment: Yes, some cases now seems working. I assumed you edit your answer now.  I am still testing cases

Comment: I assume you've figured out to ignore the 0th element.

Comment: No, I didn't figured out the 0th element either but we can we use it like this? `[1] => 10 [2] => LONG AUD/USD`  can be `echo $m[1].' '.$m[2];`

Comment: Check out the testing structure I put in there - it'll speed up your testing. I'm leaving you to figure out what to do with the empty elements and choosing when/how various elements get joined together or whatever. My answer is just the regex...

Comment: thats solved much of my issue. Thank you very much for the regex and help in term of fixes. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73479/discussion-between-peter-bowers-and-testing).